# How to connect from a docker container with web service to another docker container with MySQL using JDBC?

Tags: docker, jdbc, docker-compose

Cannot connect to MySQL running in a docker container from another docker container using JDBC. I can connect outside of docker to each container so I know they're running. But container to container using JDBC does not work for me.

Based on my docker-compose file, I've currently tried multiple combinations of JDBC including (for the JDBC URL) localhost, 0.0.0.0, 127.0.0.1, internal and external ports, container_name, db name, and other combinations.

I've also tried adding an environment clause to the docker-compose file.

Also tried using the internal docker network name.

Searched StackOverflow and tried any suggestion that seemed like it would work.

Example JDBC syntax using db container name:

"jdbc:mysql://test-mysql-docker:3306/ZipCodeLookup?useSSL=false&" +
                        "serverTimezone=America/New_York&user=root&password=thepass&autoReconnect=true";

```
version: '3'
services:
   app:
      build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      ports:
        - "8089:8080"
      volumes:
        -  /Users/mike/Library/apache-tomcat-9.0.7/conf/tomcat-users.xml:/usr/local/tomcat/conf/tomcat-users.xml
      depends_on: 
        - db

   db:
      image: mysql
      container_name: test-mysql-docker
      ports:
           - 3307:3306
      volumes:
       - ./ZipCodeLookup.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ZipCodeLookup.sql
      environment:
           MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "thepass"
```

Expected result would be the SQL zip code result from the service running in the first docker container "app".

Actual result is an error that the service could not contact the database after trying three times.

Comment: Are you giving MySQL an appropriate amount of time to initialize before attempting to connect? The `depends_on` only monitors the container status, not necessarily the application(s) inside the container.

Comment: That's a good question. The service app is available right away and I can access it from a browser (GET). The window where the docker-compose window output says MySQL is up and ready for requests.  So, given the docker-compose file above, what JDBC syntax would you use and expect to work? Thanks.

Comment: I also wanted to mention that I can access the MySQL docker container outside of docker using a regular Java program and JDBC. In that case, for JDBC, I just use localhost and port (from my docker-compose file above), 3307. Works fine. But just won't connect at all from the Java app in the other docker container to the MySQL docker container using any of the JDBC combinations I've tried. I'm seriously out of ideas. Thanks to any things to try.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that my WAR file was cached and even though I did a docker down, subsequent rebuilds, using docker up, was using that cached war file.

So, doing a "docker system prune -af" between builds (probably a better way), actually allowed me to try different builds.

SOLUTION: Use the mysql container name defined in the docker-compose.  In my case, this was the correct JDBC (from docker-compose above):

```
    final String DATABASE_URL =
            "jdbc:mysql://test-mysql-docker:3306/ZipCodeLookup?useSSL=false&" +
                    "serverTimezone=America/New_York&user=root&password=thepass&autoReconnect=true";
```

Hope this helps someone else, too. :)

Thanks to all.